# letting docker image interacting with host enviroment

Tags: python, macos, docker, filesystems

I really need help in docker.

my docker file look like:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

LABEL author="alaa"
LABEL description="Dockerfile for Python script which generates emails"
RUN pip install tqdm
COPY email_generator.py /app/
CMD python3 /app/email_generator.py
```

my pthon code looks like:

```
import json  # to read json files
import os  # to access operation for get and changing directory


def writeTextFile(text, index):
    f = open(ziel + '/email_%s.txt' % index, 'w+')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()


def writeHashFile(text):
    f = open(ziel + '/00_Hash.json', 'w+')
    f.write(str(text))
    f.close()


def readJsonCordinate(fileName):
    """Read the json data."""
    with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # Opening the file
        data = json.load(f)  # Read the json file
    return data
```

and so on...

my question is if i want to get files from the host system after building the image there i get this error. but if i run the code nativly on pycharm in my macOS it runs perfectly

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/email_generator.py", line 112, in <module>
    betreff = readJsonCordinate(quelle + '/Betreff.json')
  File "/app/email_generator.py", line 22, in readJsonCordinate
    with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # Opening the file
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/soso/desktop/email_generator/Worterbuecher/Betreff.json'
```

Comment: Why do you want to run it in Docker?  As you've already identified, it's vastly easier to interact with local files not in Docker.  You can run your application in a Python virtual environment if you need a locally installed set of packages or otherwise basic isolation from the system environment.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you haven't copied the file that the error is about into the docker.

Check if the file is present in the docker image:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint="" <image-name>:<image-tag> /bin/sh
```

and type into console:

```
find / -iname 'Betreff.json'
```

to find that file inside the image, and change path in you python so it works with updated path

Or you can add as mapped dir the dir that contains this file by using `-v` flag this way:

```
docker run -v /Users/soso/desktop/email_generator/Worterbuecher/:/Users/soso/desktop/email_generator/Worterbuecher/ ... some other opitons <docker-image>:<docker-tag>
```

more info about [docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) look for the option of -v or --volume for details

Comment: I have to get the path of the files int the host machine from the user interact with them and save files into preffered destination.

Comment: @Alaa then copy the missing file into the app directory, change path in your python app to new path and build the image again.

Comment: Maybe I did not explained it well: here what I have to do:I have to get the path of the files on the host machine from the user, interact with them and then save the output files into preffered destination also gotten from user on the host machine.

Comment: @Alaa then you need something like a dynamic volume which is not present in docker to the best of my knowledge. Docker container starts with a path that is defined before and cannot (in my opinion even shouldn't) be changed. What you can do is to not start docker by run command directly but with a CLI script that asks a user about the source and destination paths and then starts dokcer with docker run command where it puts these paths as parameters (--volume). This requires starting docker container with new paths whenever user wants to have different ones.

Comment: according to the code over there what practically I can write to have my code running with a predefined path in the python app or from a given path from the user

Answer (score 0):

You can't access files on VM using VM file paths.

It's because container filesystem is virtually disconnected from VM filesystem.

You can map VM directories and files to container using [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Then python program will be able to access mapped files and directories from within container using container paths.